# Strange problems with ConstraintLayout and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I've got some problems. with Costraint Layout and Toolbar. I upload some images to explain better what happens. I can't do nothing. If I add a new button It doesn't show it. I don't know if it is a normal situation, but if you have a solution, please, help me.
Thanks in advance[image]

[image]
[image]

enter image description here

Comment: can you check if you've added constraintlayout dependency in app-level build.gradle?

Comment: It happens sometimes the studio doesn't render properly. One reason could be outdated sdk build tools. Try updating those.

Comment: yes, I have added it

Answer (score 0):

change your android api target to 25 in your gradle file

Answer (score -1):

Change your `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and then add below code and see what happens:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: but i would use costraint. It is so strange

Comment: you can't because for constraint, you should have a constraint. for example have a textview **above** image or at specific coordination.

Comment: but the problem is that I can't add nothing because. If I add something it doesn't show nothing

Comment: But what about the toolbar?? I cannot continue my app project without it

Comment: you can have it both in layout and programmaticaly. refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html).

Comment: I can try to unistall and then install Android studio again

Comment: uninstall  and install won't change anything. just type your app bar in text part of your layout!!! in second picture you sent, you have nothing there, then what do you expect? (to have app bar?)